# Trouble comparing QTableWidgetItems to QStringList items

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

I build a QStringList from a file:

```
QFile myTextFile("/home/user/Desktop/file.txt");
QStringList myStringList;
if (!myTextFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        QMessageBox::information(0, "Error opening file", myTextFile.errorString());
    }
else
    {  
        while(!myTextFile.atEnd())
        {
            myStringList.append(myTextFile.readLine());
        }
        myTextFile.close();
    }
```

...the QTableWidget is created and populated, I then want to mark those items in row 5 that match one of the items in myStringList:

```
int rows = ui->tableWidget->rowCount();
for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
{
    QString str1 = ui->tableWidget->item(i, 5)->text();
    if (myStringList->contains(str1))
    //if(ui->tableWidget->item(i, 5)->text() == "targetstring")
    {
        ui->tableWidget->item(i, 5)->setBackgroundColor(Qt::blue);
    }
}
```

This compiles, but segfaults on execution. Table exists and is fully populated at this point. If I explicitly pass the targetstring (line commented out) it works fine, but I need to check it against the StringList.

Any suggestions appreciated, been driving me nuts!

Comment: Did you call `QTableWidget::setItem` for each item? What does `qDebug() << ui->tableWidget->item(i, 5)` outputs?

Comment: Yes, all cells have been set using setItem. Items created with QTableWidgetItem *abcItem = new QTableWidgetItem(QString::fromStdString(abc.ToString())); .qDebug doesn't work but QTextStream(stdout) << ui->tableWidget->item(i, 5);gives me a lot of hex gibberish. The file contents display correctly though when I stick QString listitems = myStringList.join(",") in a message popup.

Comment: In the last piece of code you wrote `myStringList->`. Is this a copy-paste mistake, or is `myStringList` a pointer? Is it valid?

Comment: It was a pointer as myStringList was constructed elsewhere. I have cured the problem by bringing the StringList code into the same function as the comparison code and unpointerising the variables. I also had to add a' if (rows >1)' check before the row iteration loop, as despite the table being fully populated on screen in front of me, somehow the search loop was executing ahead of whatever the tablewidget was still apparently doing. Thanks for the hint! Oh, and had to 'QString listitems = myStringList.join("");' and run the check against that, couldn't get it to work with the string list.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

```
I then want to mark those items in row 5
```

but in code you set to 5 column:

```
QString str1 = ui->tableWidget->item(i, 5 <- here)->text();
QTableWidgetItem *  item(int row, int column) const
```

I think you have only one column, anyway check size of yours table (output table rows and columns count and check it, because your code looks like really unsafe even for prototype).

Comment: Sorry, I meant column! I'm definitely targeting the right column.

Comment: Can you give me what qDebug() outputs on "qDebug() << ui->tableWidget->rowCount() << ui->tableWidget->columnCount()"? and file content maybe.